# How to loop through a list of single element object in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, object

So I have this list of cities and I want to loop through the list to have geolocation data. The API I use returns that json like `{"data":[{"lat": val, "long": val, "otherstuff": someval}],"otherdata":[{}]}`.
I'm interested in getting latitude and longitude. And I'm looping like this:

```
for city in Cities:
   lat = get_geolocation(city)['data'][0]['lat']
   lon = get_geolocation(city)['data'][0]['lon']
   Item = {
              'place':city,
              'lat':lat,
              'lon':lon
          }
```

When I'm trying to print I'm getting the error `list index must be integer not string`. So I've tried to put the result of the get_geolocation in another variable like this:

```
geo = get_geolocation(city)['data'][0]
lat = geo['lat']
lon = geo['lon']
```

Now I'm getting certain results but I also got in my output the error `list index out of range`.

I've tried different cuts in my code but I always got one of the two previous error. Can I get some help from u guys please?

Note: My list have not duplicates elements

Comment: I assume `Cities` in your loop is the name of the json? have you tried something similar to this?
```for i in Cities['data']:
    print(i['lat'], i['long'])```

Comment: @AmriRasyidi Cities is just a list of string that are cities names. The geolocation function take a string for input

Comment: what is the return of geolocation?

Comment: @AmriRasyidi it's a json like this `{"data":[{"lat": val, "long": val, "otherstuff": someval}],"otherdata":[{}]}`

Comment: You can see the return of geolocation [here](https://positionstack.com/) if you want to

Comment: are you sure the `get_geolocation(city)` return the correct value and in the correct format i.e dictionary? I think your code should work properly if it is

Comment: @AmriRasyidi yeah i'm pretty sure. But i'm still getting the same error

Comment: try `geo = get_geolocation(city)['data'][0]` and then `lat = geo['lat']` and `lon = geo['lon']` does it help? you use '0' (string) instead of 0 (integer) in your code, I'm not sure if this is a typo only in this question or your code also use string

Comment: @AmriRasyidi I've already tried it but I got the same error

Comment: By looking on API's Doc page, I assume that you probably missed the `['results']` after `['data']`.

Comment: @AntonyPhoenix I dont think there's a ['results'] after data in the doc. After data there's is a single object list